# how to fix Android Native Crash from libc.so, libart.so

Tags: android, crash, .so

Our App does not contain any c/c++ code, while we use some third part sdk who contains .so

Now, we found a big percent native crash?

we can not find useful info to get which sdk to bear the responsibility.
And the crash point to , like "libc.so", "libart.so" and "/system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat"

So, what can i do to solve the crashs?
to upgrade sdk? but I dont known which to upgrade

I can not get any info of our app...

==========================================

```
Process Name: 'com.xxxxxxxxxxx'
Thread Name: 'RenderThread'
pid: 23247, tid: 13872  >>> com.xxxx <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    r0 00000000  r1 00003630  r2 00000006  r3 b71adb30
    r4 b71adb44  r5 b71adb28  r6 00005acf  r7 0000016b
    r8 b71adb40  r9 b71adb30  10 b71adb60  fp b71adb50
    ip 00003630  sp b71adb00  lr e6ed9deb  pc e6ed9dfe  cpsr 
    008f0030
    d0  696c657069504c47  d1  6e65704f61696b53
    d2  7577682f7362696c  d3  696c657069702f69
    d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
    d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 ffffffffffffffff  d17 2e6761742e676f6c
    d18 e6eb8769e6eb8761  d19 e6eb8775e6eb8771
    d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    d22 0000000000fffdd6  d23 0000000000ffff5a
    d24 0000000000ffffeb  d25 0000000001000000
    d26 0000000000000000  d27 000000000000001d
    d28 0000000000000000  d29 000000001d000000
    d30 00d600d600d600d6  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 28000093

    #00  pc 0002ddfe  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort)
    #00  pc 0002ddfe  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so
    #01  pc 0002ddeb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so
    --- --- ---
[DEBUG] Read self maps instead! map: 0x0
    00 pc 0002ddfe  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so 
  (abort+165)
    01 pc 00001aad  liblog.so (__android_log_assert+176)
    02 pc 00124ff7  libhwui.so
    03 pc 00122bdd  libhwui.so
    04 pc 00122131  libhwui.so
    05 pc 001308b9  libhwui.so
    06 pc 0013070b  libhwui.so
    07 pc 000039af  libutils.so 
    (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+210)
    08 pc 0007a22d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so 
    (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+20)
    09 pc 0002f2a9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so 
   (__start_thread+30)
--- --- ---
    --- --- --- ---

memory near r1:
    00003630 -------- -------- -------- --------  ................

memory near r3:
    b71adaf0 e662537d b71adb28 00005acf 0000007e  }Sb.(....Z..~...
    b71adb00 b71adb70 b71adb80 b71adb90 b71adba0  p...............
    b71adb10 a6363000 8e60f3d2 00021d02 a8b02323  .06...`.....##..
    b71adb20 0000000f 00000003 ffffffdf ffffffff  ................
    b71adb30 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 00005acf  .............Z..
    b71adb40 00002735 00000000 00000000 00000000  5'..............
    b71adb50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adb60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adb70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adb80 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adb90 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adba0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adbb0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    b71adbc0 b71adbf8 e662537d e918f0b2 d722ad50  ....}Sb.....P.".
    b71adbd0 0000007e b71ae060 ffffffff b71ae060  ~...`.......`...
    b71adbe0 9434e1bc e9191ab1 e6608a45 b71ae00c  ..4.....E.`.....
```

Comment: Did you try to debug those .so files ? May be [this](https://proandroiddev.com/debugging-native-crashes-in-android-apps-2b86fd7113d8) will help.

Comment: I am a new comer to Native. cry!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixing native crashes from external SDKs is always hard. One try would be to check the whole stack trace you get when the crash occurs. There might be just hex addresses on the very top, but somewhere deeper down there might be some lines of code, which might actually help you. See for example this crash we had in our app:

```
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> one.realnote.app <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000fc40d4  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-SbkhfyZZQu51a6XNR_3aGQ==/base.apk!libarcore_c.so (offset 0x6e0000)
  #00  pc 0000000000fc358c  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-SbkhfyZZQu51a6XNR_3aGQ==/base.apk!libarcore_c.so (offset 0x6e0000)
  #00  pc 0000000000fc29ec  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-SbkhfyZZQu51a6XNR_3aGQ==/base.apk!libarcore_c.so (offset 0x6e0000)
  #00  pc 0000000000fc2478  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-SbkhfyZZQu51a6XNR_3aGQ==/base.apk!libarcore_c.so (offset 0x6e0000)
  #00  pc 0000000001951958  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-SbkhfyZZQu51a6XNR_3aGQ==/base.apk!libarcore_c.so (offset 0x6e0000)
  #00  pc 000000000193eb2c  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-SbkhfyZZQu51a6XNR_3aGQ==/base.apk!libarcore_c.so (offset 0x6e0000) (ArSession_update+152)
  #00  pc 000000000000eb8c  /data/app/one.realnote.app-g6hR_qK9swLsb5Br8mzp-Q==/base.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so (offset 0x6a1000) (Java_com_google_ar_core_Session_nativeUpdate+48)
  #00  pc 0000000000076cfc  /data/app/one.realnote.app-g6hR_qK9swLsb5Br8mzp-Q==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+140)
  #00  pc 00000000020c90c0  /memfd:/jit-cache (com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.onBeginFrame+368)
  #00  pc 00000000020d1274  /memfd:/jit-cache (com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrameNoRepost+164)
  #00  pc 00000000020c259c  /memfd:/jit-cache (com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrame+172)
  #00  pc 0000000000a2bed4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks+692)
  #00  pc 0000000000a2c668  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.Choreographer.doFrame+1224)
  #00  pc 0000000000b07038  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run+72)
  #00  pc 00000000007eeadc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+76)
  #00  pc 00000000007f21b8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1448)
  #00  pc 0000000000552294  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+772)
  #00  pc 00000000001375b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #00  pc 00000000001460cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+276)
  #00  pc 00000000004b24b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #00  pc 00000000004b3f00  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1472)
  #00  pc 000000000043f658  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+48)
  #00  pc 00000000000c8c34  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180)
  #00  pc 0000000000aaa8f8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136)
  #00  pc 0000000000ab3044  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3012)
  #00  pc 00000000001375b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #00  pc 00000000001460cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+276)
  #00  pc 00000000004b24b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #00  pc 00000000004b2118  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+408)
  #00  pc 00000000003bc968  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+624)
  #00  pc 00000000000eeafc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+116)
  #00  pc 00000000000f1c1c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+804)
  #00  pc 00000000000034f0  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1184)
  #00  pc 000000000007e86c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108)
```

Some hex counters but somewhere inside you can see calls like `com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrameNoRepost+164`, which gives you the crashing SDK (ARCore for us) but also the area of where it crashes. this way you can check in your code, where you have contact points with that specific SDK behavior, and check for possible errors on your side. If you are not already doing so, I recommend using Firebase Crashlytics with native support to get your stack traces in an online console.

Comment: Is this stack actually from Crashlytics? It looks like logcat output. I ask as we have not seen any frame information from bundled libraries (libart, libc, etc..) in Crashlytics reports. we only see file, line number, method information for our first party library.

Comment: This is actually from the Google Play developer console

Comment: I'm sorry, I see that. I was google searching for Crashlytics related topics and wound up here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem recently.

There is a high probability of a crash, not only for the "RenderThread" thread, but also for the "FinalizerDaemon" thread, "HeapTaskDaemon" thread, main thread, or JNI callback thread.

I tested the code bit by bit and finally discovered the reason why my code caused a high probability of crashing.

The reason for this issue is that my JNI dynamic library is compiled from multiple CPP source code files, and I have defined the same structure alias and the same static global unique_ptr variable in different CPPs.

A.cpp and B.cpp both have the following code:

```cpp
using CallbackObjInfo = struct {
    ……
};
static std::unique_ptr<CallbackObjInfo> g_callback;

static jboolean InitCallback(JNIEnv *env, jobject stateCallback) {
    ……
    std::unique_ptr<CallbackObjInfo> callback = std::make_unique<CallbackObjInfo>();
    ……
    g_callback= std::move(callback);
}
```

Finally, defining different structural aliases and global static variable names in A.cpp and B.cpp respectively solved this problem.

I hope my experience can be helpful to you.